# find command operator associativity and its effect to execution speed

Tags: linux, find

Let's say in a folder structure there are files of extensions `ext1`, `ext2`, `ext3` (in the decreasing order of number of files in each type), and some other files that we don't really care (in total, there are possibly 100,000s of files)

Is there a speed difference in the following, since `ext1` is likelier than `ext2`?

```
find . -name "*.ext1" -or -name "*.ext2" -or -name "*.ext3"
find . -name "*.ext3" -or -name "*.ext2" -or -name "*.ext1"
... other permutations ...
```

This assumes left-to-right associativity in the `or` operator. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested GNU `find` inside a tmpfs. (You used non-portable `-or`, so *maybe* your `find` is GNU `find`.)

---

#### Preparation

This is what I used to create 25,000,000 regular files:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
exts=(ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext1 ext2 ext2 ext2 ext3)
for d in d{0000..4999}; do
   mkdir -p "$d"
   (
   cd "$d" || exit 1
   for f in f{0000..4999}; do
      : >"$f.${exts[RANDOM%16]}"
   done
   )
done
```

For each file the code chooses the extension randomly and the theoretical distribution is:

```
ext1:ext2:ext3 = 12:3:1
```

I confirmed there are 25,000,000 regular files (`find . -type f | wc -l`). In my tests the actual numbers of files with different extensions (from `find . -name "*.ext1"` etc.) were:

- `ext1` – 18747859 – about 12/16 x 25M, as expected
- `ext2` – 4689687 – about 3/16 x 25M, as expected
- `ext3` – 1562454 – about 1/16 x 25M, as expected

---

#### Tests

There is no need to flush cache before each test, as [tmpfs is the cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500700/108618). This is how I tested:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sequence() {
   repeat=$1
   shift
   printf -- '---\n%sx' "$repeat"
   printf -- ' %s' "$@"
   for e do
      shift
      set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$e"
   done
   shift
   time for ((i=0; i<repeat; i++)); do
      find . "$@" >/dev/null
   done
}

sequence 10 ext1 ext2 ext3
sequence 10 ext1 ext3 ext2
sequence 10 ext2 ext1 ext3
sequence 10 ext2 ext3 ext1
sequence 10 ext3 ext1 ext2
sequence 10 ext3 ext2 ext1

sequence 10 ext3 ext2 ext1
sequence 10 ext3 ext1 ext2
sequence 10 ext2 ext3 ext1
sequence 10 ext2 ext1 ext3
sequence 10 ext1 ext3 ext2
sequence 10 ext1 ext2 ext3

echo

sequence 10 ext1 ext2
sequence 10 ext1 ext3
sequence 10 ext2 ext3
sequence 10 ext2 ext1
sequence 10 ext3 ext1
sequence 10 ext3 ext2

sequence 10 ext3 ext2
sequence 10 ext3 ext1
sequence 10 ext2 ext1
sequence 10 ext2 ext3
sequence 10 ext1 ext3
sequence 10 ext1 ext2

echo

sequence 10 ext1
sequence 10 ext2
sequence 10 ext3

sequence 10 ext3
sequence 10 ext2
sequence 10 ext1

echo

sequence 10 ext4

sequence 10 ext4
```

(The sequences of sequences repeat as reversed to mitigate impact of any dependence on the previous sequence; but there's probably no impact.)

---

#### Raw results

My raw results are below (almost raw; tabs have been expanded to spaces; the site would do it anyway, just worse). `10x extK extL …` means 10 invocations of `find . …` with `-name "*.extK" -o -name "*.extL" -o …` have been measured by the `time` builtin, the times are just below.

```
---
10x ext1 ext2 ext3
real    2m32,247s
user    1m40,585s
sys     0m51,656s
---
10x ext1 ext3 ext2
real    2m37,432s
user    1m45,416s
sys     0m51,992s
---
10x ext2 ext1 ext3
real    1m55,497s
user    1m4,254s
sys     0m51,236s
---
10x ext2 ext3 ext1
real    2m18,621s
user    1m27,806s
sys     0m50,814s
---
10x ext3 ext1 ext2
real    1m51,599s
user    1m0,787s
sys     0m50,808s
---
10x ext3 ext2 ext1
real    2m10,800s
user    1m19,634s
sys     0m51,165s
---
10x ext3 ext2 ext1
real    2m10,505s
user    1m19,051s
sys     0m51,453s
---
10x ext3 ext1 ext2
real    1m51,650s
user    1m0,522s
sys     0m51,128s
---
10x ext2 ext3 ext1
real    2m18,674s
user    1m27,835s
sys     0m50,838s
---
10x ext2 ext1 ext3
real    1m55,752s
user    1m4,960s
sys     0m50,791s
---
10x ext1 ext3 ext2
real    2m35,521s
user    1m43,698s
sys     0m51,822s
---
10x ext1 ext2 ext3
real    2m32,456s
user    1m40,719s
sys     0m51,733s

---
10x ext1 ext2
real    2m7,787s
user    1m16,501s
sys     0m51,285s
---
10x ext1 ext3
real    2m10,536s
user    1m19,645s
sys     0m50,877s
---
10x ext2 ext3
real    2m5,538s
user    1m14,720s
sys     0m50,811s
---
10x ext2 ext1
real    1m48,453s
user    0m57,699s
sys     0m50,744s
---
10x ext3 ext1
real    1m48,495s
user    0m58,017s
sys     0m50,475s
---
10x ext3 ext2
real    2m2,048s
user    1m10,816s
sys     0m51,218s
---
10x ext3 ext2
real    2m2,034s
user    1m11,322s
sys     0m50,702s
---
10x ext3 ext1
real    1m49,923s
user    0m58,695s
sys     0m51,212s
---
10x ext2 ext1
real    1m49,566s
user    0m58,463s
sys     0m51,097s
---
10x ext2 ext3
real    2m9,148s
user    1m16,823s
sys     0m52,298s
---
10x ext1 ext3
real    2m11,738s
user    1m20,098s
sys     0m51,635s
---
10x ext1 ext2
real    2m8,252s
user    1m16,468s
sys     0m51,782s

---
10x ext1
real    1m40,265s
user    0m49,733s
sys     0m50,523s
---
10x ext2
real    1m37,325s
user    0m45,893s
sys     0m51,419s
---
10x ext3
real    1m35,712s
user    0m43,861s
sys     0m51,843s
---
10x ext3
real    1m35,031s
user    0m43,405s
sys     0m51,616s
---
10x ext2
real    1m36,307s
user    0m44,767s
sys     0m51,537s
---
10x ext1
real    1m39,299s
user    0m47,972s
sys     0m51,318s

---
10x ext4
real    1m35,309s
user    0m43,013s
sys     0m52,290s
---
10x ext4
real    1m33,985s
user    0m42,482s
sys     0m51,503s
```

---

#### Processed and sorted results; preliminary analysis and comments

Non-equivalent **tests that check a single extension:**

| single extension tested | test | ▲ real time [s] per one `find` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ext4 | `-name "*.ext4"` | 9,4647 |
| ext3 | `-name "*.ext3"` | 9,53715 |
| ext2 | `-name "*.ext2"` | 9,6816 |
| ext1 | `-name "*.ext1"` | 9,9782 |

`find . -name "*.ext4"` was only to confirm that when there is a single `-name` test that gives no matches (and thus nothing to print), it takes less time than any `find` where a single `-name` test matches anything. The more frequent extension, the more time it takes to print pathnames of all the matching files (even if to `/dev/null`). Seems fine.

**Tests that check two extensions:**

| set | extensions tested (in order) | test | ▲ real time [s] per one `find` | relative speed [%] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ext2, **ext1** | `-name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext1"` | 10,90095 | 100 |
| B | ext3, **ext1** | `-name "*.ext3" -o -name "*.ext1"` | 10,9209 | 100 |
| C | ext3, **ext2** | `-name "*.ext3" -o -name "*.ext2"` | 12,2041 | 100 |
| C | **ext2**, ext3 | `-name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3"` | 12,7343 | 95.8 |
| A | **ext1**, ext2 | `-name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2"` | 12,80195 | 85.2 |
| B | **ext1**, ext3 | `-name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3"` | 13,1137 | 83.3 |

Tests in the same set are equivalent, I mean they "find" the same set of files. Then "relative speed" tells us how fast the execution was with respect to the fastest within the same set. We can see that in case of testing two extensions, the extension (in bold) more frequent than the other gives us faster execution when placed last. This is surprising (why? see below).

**Tests that check three extensions,** all equivalent one to another:

| extensions tested (in order) | test | ▲ real time [s] per one `find` | relative speed [%] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ext3, **ext1**, ext2 | `-name "*.ext3" -o -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2"` | 11,16245 | 100.0 |
| ext2, **ext1**, ext3 | `-name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext3"` | 11,56245 | 96.5 |
| ext3, ext2, **ext1** | `-name "*.ext3" -o -name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext1"` | 13,06525 | 85.4 |
| ext2, ext3, **ext1** | `-name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3" -o -name "*.ext1"` | 13,86475 | 80.5 |
| **ext1**, ext2, ext3 | `-name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3"` | 15,23515 | 73.3 |
| **ext1**, ext3, ext2 | `-name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext3" -o -name "*.ext2"` | 15,64765 | 71.3 |

"Relative speed" tells us how fast the execution was with respect to the fastest one. We can see the most frequent extension (in bold) should be placed second; the next best choice is on the third position. This is another surprise (why? see below).

---

#### Theory and why the above results are surprising

The [POSIX specification of `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html) states:

> `expression  -o  expression`
> Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.

I haven't found if `A -o B -o C` shall be interpreted as `A -o ( B -o C )` or `( A -o B ) -o C`, but it doesn't matter. It's a known fact these parentheses don't change the logical outcome. When in comes to evaluation, consider this:

- In the both cases `A` is evaluated first.

  - If `A` is true then it suppresses evaluation of `B -o C` (first case) or (second case) it suppresses evaluation of `B` and then `( A -o B )` is true, so it suppresses evaluation of `C`.
  - If `A` is false then in both cases `B` is the next one to evaluate.

    - If `B` is true then it suppresses evaluation of `C` (first case) or (second case) `( A -o B )` is true, so it suppresses evaluation of `C`.
    - If `B` is false then in both cases `C` is evaluated.

This means the sequence of evaluation is `A`, `B`, `C` and the first expression that evaluates to true suppresses evaluation of later expression(s).

This can be generalized to `A -o B -o C -o …`.

To speed up `A -o B -o …`, we want to get true as early as possible, so as many later expressions as possible are skipped (i.e. not evaluated). In the context of your question, theoretically `-name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3"` should be the fastest, because `-name "*.ext1"` has the greatest chance to give us true and `-name "*.ext3"` has the lowest chance.

My tests with GNU `find` do not agree with this though. This is why I called them surprising.

---

#### Practice and what GNU `find` really does

If you study the [manual of GNU `find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Optimisation-Options), you will learn it tries to save your time on its own:

> At certain optimisation levels, `find` reorders tests to speed up execution while preserving the overall effect; that is, predicates with side effects are not reordered relative to each other.

So the tool does not obey POSIX strictly, in general it reorders tests to get an equivalent "overall effect", in a hope to speed things up. AFAIK there is currently no way to turn this functionality off completely.

For our tests with two or three extensions, we are able to tell which extension it's best to test before which, because we know (or roughly know, or suspect) the distribution in advance. `find` cannot know this and treats each `-name` equally. Unfortunately even then (at least in case of my current GNU `find`; see "testbed" down below) its optimization engine actually reorders these tests and there is no option to make it "stable" (like [stable sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)).

The tool can tell us the new order:

```
( find -D opt /dev/null -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" >/dev/null ) 2>&1 | tail -n 2
```

gives:

```
Optimized command line:
 ( -name *.ext2 [est success rate 0,8] -o [est success rate 1] -name *.ext1 [est success rate 0,8]  ) -a [est success rate 1] -print [est success rate 1]
```

As you can see the two `-name` tests are swapped. This is why my tests with two extensions surprisingly performed better when `-name "*.ext1"` was placed last. I'm not totally sure if this behavior of GNU `find` is deterministic.

For three extensions I query GNU `find` like this:

```
( find -D opt /dev/null -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3" >/dev/null ) 2>&1 | tail -n 2
```

and I get:

```
Optimized command line:
 (  ( -name *.ext2 [est success rate 0,8] -o [est success rate 1] -name *.ext3 [est success rate 0,8]  ) -o [est success rate 1] -name *.ext1 [est success rate 0,8]  ) -a [est success rate 1] -print [est success rate 1]
```

so the real order is 2, 3, 1. This is why I got the fastest execution for `-name "*.ext3" -o -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2"`; in this case my GNU `find` reordered the tests and got the most optimal order. On the other hand when I typed the most optimal order, the tool changed it to a sub-optimal order.

---

#### Conclusion

If your `find` is totally POSIX-compliant then `-name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3"` should give you the fastest execution.

Maybe your `find` is (like) GNU `find` and it silently changes the order. In general you cannot know. Specifically with GNU `find` you can use `-D opt` and find out. Once you find out, you can rebuild the command line, so after `find` shuffles the tests, the most optimal order emerges.

---

#### But is it worth it?

In my tests I worked with 25,000,000 regular files. In the worst case I lost less than 5 seconds (15,6 s - 11,2 s). Now let's estimate:

- With less uniform distribution of extensions the differences might be bigger; but not arbitrarily bigger. If my testing for `*.ext4` takes 9,5 seconds, testing for any 3 extensions in any order should not exceed 30 seconds; so even if the best order takes no time at all (you wish!), I can lose 30 seconds at most.
- My CPU is quite fast, on a slower hardware everything would take proportionally more time and I would lose more.
- But you mentioned "100,000s of files", this is two orders of magnitude less.
- Working with HDD or SSD instead of RAM would add roughly the same "penalty", no matter the order of `-name` tests.

After all it seems we're talking about tenths of second, maybe few seconds to save. Querying GNU `find` and rebuilding the command line takes more. Even wondering which extension is more frequent than others may take more.

Unless you are going to create a command once, but run it many, many times, optimizing this way is not worth the hassle. Optimizations inside GNU `find` may make sense because they take less time than what they may save. The optimization the question is about takes more time.

---

#### Testbed

- Kubuntu 23.04
- kernel 6.2.0-31-generic
- `find` from GNU findutils 4.9.0

Comment: Asking myself if `find . -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2" -o -name "*.ext3"` shouldn't be better expressed as `find . -name "*.ext[123]"` or maybe `find . -name "*.{ext1,ext2,ext3}` :) By the same, with GNU implementation and to avoid reordering, maybe we should go with `find . -regextype egrep -regexp ".*\.ext[1-3]"` or `find . -regextype egrep -regexp ".*\.(ext1|ext2|ext3)"` :)